# How to use softlayer api client for java with proxy?

Tags: java, api, rest, proxy, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to use softlayer api using JAVA
URI:- https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java

I am using above implementation, but i am not able to connect as i have proxy on my machine.
can anyone tell me how to add proxy to the RestApiClient  object

```
.
..
RestApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(slUser,apiKey);
    Guest.Service service = Guest.service(client);
..
.
```

i get connection refused error.

Comment: Try configuring your proxy in the command line: `java -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxyHost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 MainClass`

Comment: You will need to implement a custom HttpClient.

Comment: Both @morgano and clyde-dcruz are correct. morgano's suggestion for using system properties is probably the easiest.